# Embedded links not working in downloaded pdf

Tags: latex, overleaf

When I embed a URL in my overleaf main text and compile it, upon clicking on it, it does re-direct to the addressed webpage as expected, but when I download the text as a pdf, clicking on the link has no effect. Below is an example of how I include links. What am I doing wrong?

```
\cvline{}{blah blah blah \href{https://www.semanticscholar.org/my-paper}{Link}\newline}{}
```

compiles to => blah blah blah [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67507143/embedded-links-not-working-in-downloaded-pdf)

Clicking on the link, after compiling, opens up the intended webpage, but when I download and then click on "Link", nothing happens...